# Macro Excel: Assign macro to Userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have a coding to calculate No. of x and y dies (it's actually column and row). How do I insert the coding into the UserForm to make it works? Then, after I key in the data for each x and y dies and press "Ok", I want the output to appear on my worksheet. What coding do I use for the "Ok" part? And for the "Cancel" part as well. I'm still new to VBA code.

My code:

```
Sub InsertShapeRange()

Dim my_row As Integer
Dim my_col As Integer
Dim Rng As Range
Dim shp As Shape
Dim ws As Worksheet

my_col = Application.InputBox("No. of x dies?", "Wafer Map", Default:=0)
my_row = Application.InputBox("No. of y dies?", "Wafer Map", Default:=0)

Set Rng = Selection
Set Rng = Rng.Resize(my_row, my_col)
Set ws = Rng.Parent
Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddShape(1, Rng.Left, Rng.Top, Rng.Width, Rng.Height)
With shp
    .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
    With .Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
End With
With Rng
    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With 
End Sub
```

I have a UserForm as shown below.

[image: UserForm]

Comment: When looking at the userform in the VBEditor, can't you right click "Ok", and go to View--> Code?  Or the menu, View Code?

Comment: Can. What I mean is, after I key in data for no. of x and y dies, then click "Ok", the output will appear on the worksheet. What coding should I put for the "Ok" part so that I can get the output that I want which is the rectangle shape and grid.

Comment: Does [this page](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html) help? Or [this one](http://www.contextures.com/xlUserForm01.html)?

Comment: I don't really get it. What about my coding `Sub InsertShapeRange()` ? I need the coding to do the row and column selection when I key in the number into the userform and a shape will appear in the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You could add parameters to your subroutine.

```
Sub InsertShapeRange(my_col As Integer, my_row As Integer)
```

You would then need to delete these lines, as the variables are now defined in the Sub definition :

```
Dim my_row As Integer
Dim my_col As Integer

my_col = Application.InputBox("No. of x dies?", "Wafer Map", Default:=0)
my_row = Application.InputBox("No. of y dies?", "Wafer Map", Default:=0)
```

Now add code for your Ok button when clicked by right clicking on the button and selecting View Code.

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    InsertShapeRange txtXDies, txtYDies
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

You might also want to set the Default property of the OK Button to True so that pressing the Enter Key is the same as clicking it. Ensure that the Cancel property is set to False.

[OK Button Default property = True](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8hge.png)

For the Cancel Button, enter the following code to hide the form.

```
Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Finally set the Cancel property of the Cancel button to True like so. This makes pressing the Escape key equivalent to clicking it. Also set Default to False.

[Cancel Property of Cancel Button = True](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI8ur.png)

The completed Form Code module will look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    InsertShapeRange txtXDies, txtYDies
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

The completed InsertShapeRange subroutine will now look like this.

```
Sub InsertShapeRange(my_col As Integer, my_row As Integer)

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set Rng = Selection
    Set Rng = Rng.Resize(my_row, my_col)
    Set ws = Rng.Parent
    Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, Rng.Left, Rng.Top, Rng.Width, Rng.Height)
    With shp
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        With .Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            .Transparency = 0
        End With
    End With
    With Rng
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With

End Sub
```

In my example the Text Boxes are named "txtXDies" and "txtYDies", the OK Button "cmdOK", and Cancel Button "cmdCancel". You can check the names or rename them in the Properties Window - press F4 and click on the object.

Comment: Where do I put the completed `InsertShapeRange` subroutine? in UserForm or Sheet1/Module?

Comment: It will work in either.  Simplest would be to put in in the UserForm code below the button click event code. Myself, I would put it into a new module not in the UserForm, and not in Sheet1 so that I can run it easily without the form. If you want to do that, Create a new module by right clicking on the Modules folder in the Project Explorer on the left. Select Insert, and then Module (not UserForm or Class Module).

Comment: Also as a matter of style and readability, I would use msoShapeRectangle instead of the number 1. I've edited my answer to show that. Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, ....) All the best with learning to program. Don't be afraid to experiment and see what happens. (As long as you're not learning how to delete files, that is... Yes, I learnt that the hard way.)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try.